# Can't convert image buffer to base64 string

Tags: node.js, buffer, png

In my server, I am receiving a POST request for multipart form data in which I receive a PNG image file. I used Buffer.slice() to get the original PNG image. But while experimenting with the formatted Buffer I found that:

```
console.log(requestBody.compare(Buffer.from(requestBody.toString('base64'))));
```

This statement returns -1. ( Here requestBody is the formatter image buffer )
My doubt is shouldn't this statement return 0 because I am converting the same buffer to string and then back to buffer ?

My code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const qs = require('querystring');
const path = require('path');

http.createServer(function ( request, response ) {

  if ( request.method == 'GET' ) {
    fs.readFile('./views/index.html', function ( error, data ) {
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
      response.end(data);
    });
  } else if ( request.method == 'POST' ) {
    let requestBody = null;
    request.on('data', function( data ) {
      if ( requestBody == null ) {
        requestBody = data;
      } else {
        requestBody += data;
      }
    });
    request.on('end', function( data) {
      requestBody = Buffer.from(requestBody.slice(requestBody.indexOf('image/png') + 13, requestBody.lastIndexOf('------')-1));
      console.log(requestBody.compare(Buffer.from(requestBody.toString('base64'))));
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'image/png'});
      response.end(requestBody);
    });
  }

}).listen(3000);
```